# Parsing JSON in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a HTTP listener that I am sending a JSON post body with.

```
{
"recipient":"bob@example.com",
"subject":"this is a test subject",
"body":"this is a test body email"
}
```

I am trying to pull those individual parameters out in the next flow, but it errors instead!

The result I am looking to achieve is "bob@example.com" being taken as an input for the next action

I've tried things like

```
"@{triggers().outputs.body.Content.recipient}"
```

and various variations of, but I suspect I'm missing something!

**edit to add**

I am currently sending the post request via Powershell, though it will ultimately be over c#

```
$a = @"
{"recipient":"bob@example.com","subject":"this is a test subject","body":"this is a test body email"}
"@

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri     https://httplistenerc743421edf234899a1315aa38c6398bc.azurewebsites.net/listen -Method POST -Body $a
```

Comment: How are you sending the JSON POST?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin via Powershell - see edit

Comment: Did you use basically this process to setup the listener? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-http/ I want to ensure I am answering the right question.

Comment: Yes, the listener works fine, if I just put "@{triggers().outputs.body.Content}" then it will forward the entire JSON wherever I want it to (I'm testing it in a slack connector) but I want to deserialize the JSON into its components

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Much appreciated - and note to self, delete that listener now I've posted it to the universe ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah the trick with this is the output of the HTTP Listener body is a String, so you need to convert it to JSON before you can parse it.  There is a @parse() command to do just this.

So if you do this it should work:

@{json(trigger().outputs.body.Content).recipient}

That should give you the recipient.  Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: that works perfectly! thank you - On a related note, I'm wondering if it is worth a question about how to discover these things (or if it just comes from someone who programs these things rather than hacks about with them like I do!)

Comment: It's a good question.  The syntax docs can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/dn948512.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but we are working hard to make sure that's easier to find.  Always welcome to reach out to me directly as well if you have any questions (or feedback, we love that too :).  jehollan[at]microsoft.com

Comment: Just an FYI,`@parse` is now deprecated. Use `@json` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define content-type in header of http listener, after which you don't need to parse http listener's response, it will automatically in described format.

Answer (score 1):

as i did with mine where azure function is returning json data as text/string:

```
@{body('azure_fun_Name').recipient}
@{body('azure_fun_Name').subject}
@{body('azure_fun_Name').body}
```